# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException)

Tags: java, android, flutter, exoplayer, video-player

I am using `video_player: any` in flutter. I am using https server url. All things are working fine, I am able to call api, load images but when I try to load video, I am getting this errors.

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error
  com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:580)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
 Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: Unable to connect
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:346)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1016)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:417)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:239)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:1471)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:1415)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:1359)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:221)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:144)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:106)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:400)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:333)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:483)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:135)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:608)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:513)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:339)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84) 
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1016) 
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:417) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
 Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:668)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:513)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:432)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:360)
    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:89)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:224)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:430)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:387)
      at com.a
E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null)
```

I have added security config as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<domain-config>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">dxb.suphub.net</domain>
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="@raw/my_ca"/>
    </trust-anchors>
</domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and in Manifest file, I have added following command

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Still I am getting this error, Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Is the Certificate Authority (CA) installed and trusted on your device?

Comment: @Boris no but what if i release application then everyone should not hve that CA installed on their phone right?

Comment: I don't know that.

Comment: do you solve this problem?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue ?  -@JitendraModi

Comment: @Pruthvi No, Issue still persists